# Get MYSQL to nest results

Tags: mysql

Hi i'm trying get MYSQL to nest results.

here's an example raw database.

```
id     name     parent_id
21     ccc      NULL
23     ccc      48
24     aaa      NULL
25     ddd      24
26     eee      NULL
48     bbb      NULL
```

I need it output in this order

```
id     name     parent_id
24     aaa      NULL
25     ddd      24
48     bbb      NULL
23     ccc      48
21     ccc      NULL
26     eee      NULL
```

I need MYSQL to sort the names in order while nesting the "child" names immediately after the "parent_id". The order amongst the child names will also be sorted by the name.

How can i get MYSQL to nest the table for me?

Comment: And what is the logic for the expected result ?

Comment: As @Abhik says, you're not telling us the pattern for how you are determining the results. In describing this pattern, to us but more importantly yourself, it should become clear how to achieve your desired result.

Comment: sorry i wasn't clear. I need MYSQL to sort the names in order while nesting the "child" names immediately after the "parent_id". The order amongst the child names will also be sorted by the name.

Comment: You are going to struggle to get this order the way you want purely in SQL using an adjacency list model like you propose. I would in fact questoin the value of doing this in SQL, as you will likely need to read the adjacency list into an appropriate tree-like data structure in your application anyway, in which case ordering in SQL may be pointless.  You may consider nested set model which would make ordering easy.  Please see this great article to compare options - http://mikehillyer.com/articles/managing-hierarchical-data-in-mysql/  I generally prefer nested set for trees of arbitrary depth

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can use something like

```
select id, name, parent_id from
(

select c.id as id, c.name as name, p.id as parent_id, p.name as sortname , 1 as sortchild
from t as p 
join t as c on c.parent_id = p.id

union 

select id, name , id, name , 0 
from t
where parent_id is null

) X
order by sortname, parent_id, sortchild
```

see http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/16764/11

This splits the problem in to a couple of steps :

first find the child rows and join with their parents, taking the parent name for sorting and an flag to say its a child row - this bit

```
select c.id as id, c.name as name, p.id as parent_id, p.name as sortname , 1 as sortchild
    from t as p 
    join t as c on c.parent_id = p.id
```

then find all the parent rows (i.e. those with null parent_id) and include the name again for sorting

```
select id, name , id, name , 0 
from t
where parent_id is null
```

finally wrap them in a union and sort on the parent name

Answer (score 0):

This is also possible with a selfjoin only, there's no union required.
This works only with 2 levels.

```
 SELECT p.name,
      p.id,
      p.name
      c.name child_name,
      c.id child_id
 FROM
     tablename p
 LEFT JOIN
     tablename c
     ON p.id = c.parent_id
 WHERE p.parent_id IS NULL
 ORDER BY p.name, child_name
```

The WHERE makes sure only records with no parent are selected.